# In Xcode, why does LLDB respond with just "(lldb)" and no other output whenever I run a command?

Tags: xcode, lldb

When I type commands into Xcode, I get no output or error message, just another lldb prompt:

```
(lldb) e index
(lldb) frame variable
(lldb)
```

No matter what I type (valid or invalid), I just get an LLDB prompt and no output. What's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the output dropdown (in the lower-left corner of the LLDB console in Xcode) set to "Debugger Output" or "All Output":

[image]